# Excel VLookup Fill data in adjacent cells with data from other columns

Tags: excel

How can I fill data in columns B, C & D from data in columns G, H, I based on the values in column A?

Here's my original data

```
1                           1   a   b   c
2                           2   d   e   f
3                           3   g   h   i
4                           4   j   k   l
5                           5   m   n   o
6                           6   p   q   r
7                           7   s   t   u
8                           8   v   w   x
9                           9   y   z   aa
10                          10  bb  cc  dd
```

The end result

```
    1   a   b   c       1   a   b   c
    4   j   k   l       2   d   e   f
    3   g   h   i       3   g   h   i
    5   m   n   o       4   j   k   l
    2   d   e   f       5   m   n   o
    7   s   t   u       6   p   q   r
    6   p   q   r       7   s   t   u
    8   v   w   x       8   v   w   x
    10  bb  cc  dd      9   y   z   aa
    9   y   z   aa      10  bb  cc  dd
```

The `1` in column matches the `1` in `F` and pulls data from `G`, `H` & `I`

I can do this using `VLOOKUP` and only a single column, but is it possible to get `VLOOKUP` to fetch and fill data in 3 columns?

Edit:

```
aa  a   b   c
bb  d   e   f
cc  g   h   i
dd  j   k   l
ee  m   n   o
```

Entering the formula below using ctrl+shift+enter gives me only `aa`

```
{=VLOOKUP("aa",$A$1:$D$5,{1,2,3,4},FALSE)}
```

Comment: Sure. VBA would be fine...

Comment: Why can't you use `=index(G:G,match(A1,F:F,0))`, `=index(H:H,match(A1,F:F,0))` and `=index(I:I,match(A1,F:F,0))` to fill columns B,C and D?

Comment: Actually, I trying to do something like in the `How to return multiple columns from a VLOOKUP?` on this page `http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-excel/#Vlookup-Multiple` but I cant get it to return values like he does...

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when you entered the recommended array formula from the link?

Comment: Yes, I do. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: You have to replace "aa" with the cell reference, e.g. `A1`, `A2` and so on.

Comment: I did that too. It just wont work. I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working. I wasn't selecting the three cell before entering the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are following the instructions, but you need to first select Cells `B1`, `C1` and `D1` and than without clicking anywhere else type this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,F:I,{2,3,4},FALSE)
```

And then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`+`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Now keep Cells `B1`, `C1` and `D1` selected and darg it down till you have data in column A.

Here is the screenshot replicating your data:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks. I got it working. I wasn't selecting the three cell before entering the formula.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBA, you can create a simple **FOR loop** to find your values:

```
Sub CompleteColumns()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lastrow
    For y = 2 To lastrow
        If Range("A" & x).Value = Range("F" & y).Value Then
            Range("B" & x & ":D" & x).Value = Range("G" & y & ":I" & y).Value
        Exit For
        End If
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```