# Sort excel rows according to list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hi I have a excel spreadsheet (A) that looks like below. This list goes on to thousands:

```
BAR CODE | SERIAL NO. | DEVICE NO.| CELL NO.| CLIENT DETAILS | STATUS
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0001     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0002     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0003     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0004     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0005     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0006     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0007     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0008     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
```

I also have a list of the device numbers (B) like below:

```
00001
00003
00007
00008
```

I want to use the list of device numbers (B) to search the spreadsheet(A) for those specific numbers and then return the whole row containing those numbers.

An example of the outcome I want would be:

```
BAR CODE | SERIAL NO. | DEVICE NO.| CELL NO.| CLIENT DETAILS | STATUS
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0001     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0003     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0007     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0008     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
```

I have tried using the Filter tab and sort & filter but I have not been able to find a way to achieve my desired outcome.

Any help or suggestions will make me very happy thanks.

Comment: Use Advanced Filter.  It will take a list and return the entire rows.

Comment: @Scott Craner It doesn't work. I can't paste the list in the field and I can't sit clicking on 3000 check boxes.I'm using excel 2013 by the way.

Comment: Advanced filter not regular filter.

Comment: If you are okay to move `DEVICE NO.` column to first place on SS (A), then you can use **`VLOOKUP`** function [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42419687/1652222) way to get all the values from other columns for same row.

Comment: The suggested method of @ScottCraner works fine, maybe there's some need to detail the steps.

Comment: Yeah I'm new to excel

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b

Comment: Ah I found another way using the VLOOKUP formula and a new sheet1 with the lookup numbers pasted in column A. `=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)` after I ran this all i needed to do was hit Ctrl-Shift-L and select the checkbox allowing only numbers found to be returned in the new column I inserted In front of the rest.It looks just like I wanted. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(SrcRng,MATCH(DevNo,DevNoCol,0),MATCH(Title,SrcHdr,0))
```

Where:

**SrcRng:** Is the `Range` holding the source data.

**DevNo:** Is the `DEVICE NO.` from the result range.

**DevNoCol:** Is the `DEVICE NO.` column range form the source range.

**Title:** Is the corresponding cell in the header row from the target range (1st Row).

**SrcHdr:** Is the header from the source range (1st Row).

So assuming the source data in worksheet `A` is located at 'A1:F3000' and the result table is located in worksheet `B` at 'A1:F4'; the formula to apply would be:

```
=INDEX(A!$A$1:$E$3000,MATCH($C2,A!$C$1:$C$3000,0),MATCH(A$1,A!$A$1:$E$1,0))
```

Copy this formula in Columns `A`, `B`, `D` and `E` in the result table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Table and use VLookup to "sort" it

Original Table

`BAR CODE | SERIAL NO. | DEVICE NO.| CELL NO.| CLIENT DETAILS | STATUS
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0001     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0002     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0003     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0004     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0005     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0006     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0007     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
  xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0008     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx`

This will be your new table (sorting already what you need)

   `A     |     B      |     C     |     D   |       E        |   F
BAR CODE | SERIAL NO. | DEVICE NO.| CELL NO.| CLIENT DETAILS | STATUS
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0001     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0003     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0007     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx
 xxxxxx  |  xxxxxxx   |  0008     |   xxxx  |   xxxxxxxxxx   | xxxxxx`

So you will do use `=VLOOKUP(DEVICE NO., Entire Table selection, Column you want to match, 0)`:

So for column:

A:
`VLOOKUP(C2, A$1:F$#, 1, 0)`

B: 
`VLOOKUP(C2, A$1:F$#, 2, 0)`

D:
`VLOOKUP(C2, A$1:F$#, 4, 0)`

E:
`VLOOKUP(C2, A$1:F$#, 5, 0)`

("#" is the number of rows your original table have, which I have no clue)

Then you just expand the formulas for the amount of devices you want to sort.
This should definitely solve your problem. Although, if there is any question, please let me know.